# how to get a list of the possible pairs in a list of lists - python

Tags: python

I have the following list of lists

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6,7]]
```

trying to get the following result

```
b = [[1,2],[1,3],[2,3],[4,5],[4,6],[4,7],[5,6],[5,7],[6,7]]
```

I have tried to use

```
b = list(itertools.product(a))
```

but I got a combination of the first with the second. Appreciate any help thanks

Comment: I think that gives a list of tuples not a list of lists

Comment: b = list(itertools.product(*a)) gives a combination of the first list with the second

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for a solution using the standard library, this uses a list comprehension to call `itertools.combinations` on each sublist.

```
from itertools import combinations
b = [list(c) for l in a for c in combinations(l, r=2)]
b
# [[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3], [4, 5], [4, 6], [4, 7], [5, 6], [5, 7], [6, 7]]
```

---

Another very functional way of computing this is using `map`; this returns a list of tuples.

```
from itertools import chain, combinations
from functools import partial

fn = partial(combinations, r=2)
b = list(chain.from_iterable(map(fn, a))) 
b 
# [(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (4, 5), (4, 6), (4, 7), (5, 6), (5, 7), (6, 7)]
```

Comment: you can use itertools.chain to avoid a nested comprehension

Comment: @coldspeed I was thinking about something like this: `list(chain(*(combinations(l, r=2) for l in a)))` just to avoid a *nested* comprehension. Single comprehension are readable enough IMO

Comment: @Tryph I guess that's another option, although I don't usually enjoy mixing functional programming and comprehension syntax.